# How to access methods of submodules

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure

```
main.py
-packages
-__init__.py
--package1
---__init__.py
---package1.py
---__init__.py
--package2
---__init__.py
---package2.py
```

Why does the following not work in main.py:

```
importlib.import_module('packages.package1')
print(f'result: {packages.package1.main()}')
```

Error: `AttributeError: module 'packages.package1' has no attribute 'main'`
package1.py does in fact have a function named main. I also see the module in the sys.module.keys() list so it is being imported.

Edit: I am not using `import ...` as I need to import any packages added to the packages directory.

Comment: Because the function does not define any global variables. Why did you use `import_module` instead of an `import` statement (which *does* set a global variable to reference the imported module)?

Comment: @chepner I need to dynamically import any packages arbitrarily added in the packages folder

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate that at all.

Comment: @chepner The main question was "Why does X not work" not "How do I do Y" but I understand. Edits added.

Answer (score 1):

`import_module` does not bind the newly imported module to any names; it *returns* the `module` object that was just imported.

```
x = importlib.import_module('packages.package1')
print(f'result: {x.main()}')
```

Comment: So I had to do ```x = importlib.import_module('packages.sub_package1.main')
    x.main()``` but this got me on the right track. How do I get everything from the module aside from just main?